# javascript - long decimal float number accuracy

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do some floating number calculation with javascript that requires high accuracy

when I tried to initiate a variable like this:

```
const pi = 3.141592653589793238462643383280
```

System will truncate number to

```
>pi
>3.141592653589793
```

How can I do calculating with long decimal digits? thanks!

Comment: `const pi = '3.141592653589793238462643383280';`

Comment: May be you should try this. https://github.com/dtrebbien/BigDecimal.js

Comment: @ElliottFrisch, sorry I mean to say calculating with long decimal digits, not just storing it, i've updated question

Comment: @ArsalanAkhtar, thanks, BigDecimal.js seems complicated, I wonder would there be any performance penalty?

Comment: Why using javascript for high accuracy?

Comment: @Frederik.L, I'm trying to do some statistic work, accuracy is important to me, is javascript not the right language for this sort of work?

Comment: @jerry Not that I wouldn't be interested to see decent Javascript ways of managing high accuracy numbers, I feel like you will end up doing something near what the Python language does with "endless numbers". That is probably more efficient to use a native approach with Python instead of using a lib to recreate this in javascript. Just my two cents.

Comment: @Frederik.L, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a library like say for example http://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/